# Image not displaying from local html on iPhone webview

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, uiwebview, local

I am calling an infoPage.html as below with an image from Resources and referenced as img src="eye.png" in the html, the text displays correctly but I cannot load the image (only a ? appears), any suggestions...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 [super viewDidLoad];

 CGRect webRect = CGRectMake(15,40,300,450);
 UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webRect];

 myWebView.delegate = self;

 myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
 NSString *htmlPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"infoPage.html"];
 NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath];
 [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil]; 

 //stop webview from scrolling
 [[[myWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];

 [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil];

 [self.view addSubview:myWebView];

 [myWebView release];
}
```

Comment: Instead of `baseURL:nil`, try `baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [myWebView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: htmlPath]]], rather than -loadHTML so that it knows where to extract images from. Alternatively, you could pass the path in as the baseURL: argument.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of baseURL:nil, try baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]]

Comment: credit to JTBandes who posted this originally as a comment to the main question, but it needed to be an answer.  I made this a community WIKI so I get no points for upvotes or having it marked correctly, and will delete if JTBandes comes back to post his answer as an answer.

Comment: You need a URL, not a string for the baseURL